# Where and how do i call different CSS for different browsers in my MVC website?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-mvc

I am developing a website and have noticed that it does not preform correctly on all the browsers.

I Would like to create a different CSS style sheet for each browser, mainly IE.

My problem comes in on how to call the different style sheets with the different browsers.

I also cant find where the main site.css is called in my MVC website, if someone could show me where the site.css is called in a MVC website that would be great.

**So where and how do i call different style sheets for different browsers in a MVC website?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a browser specific stylesheet is no different in ASP .NET MVC. You put the `if` statement and point to the stylesheet. [See more here.](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) You can put your stylesheet statements in the `_Layout.cshtml` file in the `Views\Shared` folder

In ASP .NET MVC, the  stylesheet is in the `Content` folder.

[ASP .NET MVC 4 uses Minification and Bundling](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/389545/ASP-NET-MVC4-Bundling-and-Minification). Look inside the `App_Start` folder, you will see a BundleConfig.cs file, and inside, you will see the `bundles` that contain the css and javascript. In the `_layout.cshtl` file, you will see code that references these `bundles` ,which is something like `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")`.

*"So where and how do i call different style sheets for different browsers in a MVC website?"*

In the **Layout** file which has your `<head>` tags. like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
        <!--[if IE]>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iespecific.css" />
        <![endif]-->

    </head>
    ....
```

Comment: Hey Thanks, do you know how to do the same for FireFox?

Comment: unfortunately, the conditional comments (the `if IE`) only works for IE. for Firefox, you can use server side code to do the check `@if(Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("firefox")){add link to ff css}`. Or, you can use the `moz` css hacks ( see here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-hacks-targeting-firefox/)

Answer (score 3):

Use conditionals:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iespecific.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

or

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iespecific.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

or

```
<!--[if gte IE 6]> (greater then IE6)
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="iespecific.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

I have no clue where your css would be located in "MVC website", since i have no clue what framework you are using.

Comment: And how to i specify chrome and firefox?

Comment: Well if you need coditional javascript for every specific browser, you are definatly doing something wrong with your css. But no, there is no conditional css statement for other browsers then IE. You can however use `[if !IE]` for all non IE browsers.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this for IE:

```
<!--[if IE]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 6<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 7<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 8<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 9<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 8]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE 8 or higher<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE lower than 9<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE lower or equal to 7<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 6]>
According to the conditional comment this is IE greater than 6<br />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]> -->
According to the conditional comment this is not IE<br />
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Note the special syntax:

```
gt: greater than
lte: less than or equal to
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is actually not best practice. You should not target specific *browsers*, rather you should target *standards* (e.g. HTML5 & CSS3).

If you believe that your target audience is likely to use older browsers, then target HTML4 and CSS2.

Also...consider using CSS normalization, as opposed to having different stylesheets for different browsers.

From personal (and indeed professional) experience, I have found that when using CSS normalization, if I even have to write a browser specific stylesheet, then my global stylesheet is poorly implemented...therefore its better to build something on top of CSS normalization that works globally, than writing hacks for browsers!

**Google :** `HTML5 Boilerplate` | `CSS Normalization`

You might like to try here... http://html5boilerplate.com/

Another bit of research you might like is [Google Chrome Frame](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/)

Comment: Thanks i will take a look at this, How can i tell what standard is a browser using?

Comment: Hey That Google Chrome Frame is awesome wow, I am a bit uneasy making a user download and install something before using my site.

Comment: @Pommy, well you can test your own browser to see what it supports using this...http://html5test.com/

Comment: @Pommy, If you want to detect available features in a remote browser, you should use Modernizr (http://www.modernizr.com/)